# Performing an action when a combobox value is selected

Tags: vb.net, combobox, datagrid, selectedindexchanged

I'm having some trouble doing something that seems very simple but I just don't know what I'm doing wrong....

On Form_Load I populate a combobox with

```
Datasource
DisplayMember
ValueMember
```

Here I set .selectedindex = - 1 so that nothing is selected. The combobox gets populated properly and everything is bells and whistles.

Now when user selects something from the drop down, I want to populate a DataGrid with a bunch of info based off the VALUE selected. So I pass and ID into the function that populates the DataGrid.

I'm trying to do this like this...

```
   Private Sub cbo1_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbo1.SelectedValueChanged
    dim productID as string=""

    cbo1.SelectedValue = ProductID
    Call PopulateProductGrid(ProductID)
End Sub
```

I also have tryined with SelectedIndexChanged, but for both event I get an error

> Cannot set the SelectedValue in a ListControl with an empty
>   ValueMember.

Comment: It sound's like the `ComboBox` is not bound, that error would more than likely come from that. Please show how you are assigning the `DataSource`, `DisplayMemeber` and the `ValueMember`... Also it wouldn't hurt to show `PopulateProductGrid` does... On another note, are you sure it's a `DataGrid` and ***not a DataGridView***? Also you are setting the value in the event, I think you want to assign `ProductID = cbo1.SelectedValue` ***not*** `cbo1.SelectedValue = ProductID` which is more than likely the error you are getting.

Comment: Why are you trying to set the value in the `SelectedValueChanged` event? Where did `ProductID` come from?

Comment: @zaggler = DataGridView - and yes it is properly bound - because when I do it on Button_Click - it works fine (as in populates the datagridview).  I declare ProductID as Integer- and the selectedvalue is what I assign to it and pass it to my PopulateProductGrid

Comment: Are you sure you want cbo1.SelectedValue = ProductID and not ProductID = cbo1.SelectedValue ?

Comment: @genespos - Yes I do. Thanks!

Comment: @fabio well thats what I meant to say as in what he said was correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll wager that the issue is that you're binding in the wrong order.  You should always set the `DataSource` last, not first.  Try changing that and see if your issue goes away.  The problem is that setting the `DataSource` means that the control is bound, so an item will be selected and the appropriate events raised before you have set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`.